# How to put a div at center of another div?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have one div at center of another div horizontally.

```
    <div id="container">
        <div id="centered">
            hello world;
        </div>
    </div
```

I tried with below style with "margin: 0px auto" trick, but it only works in FF, not in IE.

```
    div
    {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    #centered
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 30px;
    }
    #container
    {
        width: 100px;
        }
```

Is there any way to achieve this cross browser?

Comment: Ahh, the bane of my existence! Who thought people would never want to vertically align elements?!

Comment: Your keyboard says "vertically" but your eyes say "horizontally".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably are not including a DOCTYPE in your document, thus throwing IE into quirks mode.

Add this at the top of your file, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

See the difference here: [with doctype](http://jsbin.com/oloja), [without doctype](http://jsbin.com/ufamu).

It is a very good practice to always include a DOCTYPE into your document to make your website be as consistent as possible across browsers. With a DOCTYPE and a reset stylesheet cross browser layouts are much more reliable.

The above DOCTYPE is just one of many choices. For more, check out [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414891/whats-up-doctype)

You may also notice that Stackoverflow's sister site aimed at designers is named after this very important aspect of web design: [Doctype](http://doctype.com/).

Comment: While it's good advice to use a DOCTYPE, that's not the issue here and it is not sufficient to do cross browser friendly vertical centering.

Answer (score 5):

See [Quirks mode and strict mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) and [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/). Basically it's good practice to force browsers (particularly IE) to be more standards-compliant by **always** using a DOCTYPE at the top of the document, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

With that all browsers will horizontally center with `margin: 0 auto`.

**Edit:** this question originally said "vertical centering, hence the answer below:

From [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Universal vertical center with CSS</title>
  <style>
    .greenBorder {border: 1px solid green;} /* just borders to see it */
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="greenBorder" style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style=" #position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
      <div class="greenBorder" style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
        any text<br>
        any height<br>
        any content, for example generated from DB<br>
        everything is vertically centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, it's complicated involving relative+absolute+relative positioning (whereas its trivial with a table cell contents).

Comment: I would of thought you'd given 'use tables' as an answer cletus! Have you gone to the dark side?

Comment: Note: That wasn't meant to be offensive, I hope it's not interpreted as such! Happy Friday :)

Comment: I'll use tables when it's too hard, impossible or not sufficiently backwards compatible to use divs.

Comment: I've used the example above before to center vertically - but it always feels ugly using so many divs. Guess we have to wait til IE8 completely overthrows IE6 + 7 so we can use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`

Comment: Even though he said vertically, I am pretty sure he meant horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

IE is a PITA. You can do it with tables deprecated markup (cringe).

```
<table width="100%" height="100%"><tr><td align="center" valign="middle">
CONTENT
</td></tr></td>
```

I'm sure you can pull it off with CSS hacks too.

Answer (score 1):

Add text-align:center; to container.
Side note: the text in the centered div will be centered also.

Comment: "text-align:center" doesn't apply to block element such as "div".

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but it's fairly fragile, so use pixels or ems, not percentages:

```
<style type="text/css">

#div1 {
    height: 20em;
    width: 30em;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    text-align:center;
}

#div2 {
    height: 5em;
    width: 5em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-bottom: -25%;
    line-height: 5em;
}
</style>

<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">Woot!</div>
</div>
```

I just set the top margin to 25% and the bottom to -25%. Seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

... here div class="content" on center of div position:relative ...

```
<style>

 .wrapper {
     width:200px;/* this is size range */
      height:100px;  
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;top:50%;
 visibility:hidden;
}

.content {
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;height:100%;
 left:-50%;top:-50%;
 visibility:visible;
}

</style>

<div style="position:relative;width:500px;height:400px;background:#ff00ff;">

  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="content">

   ... so you has div  on center ...

   </div>
  </div>

</div>
```