# Showing different textbox width in different pages

Tags: html, css, width, padding

I have following textbox in my first HTML page:

```
<input tabindex="4" type="text" class="search_textbox roundedCorners" id="search_query" name="search_query"/>

.roundedCorners{        
  border:1px solid black;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
.search_textbox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 187px; 
  height: 21px;    
  left: 96px;
  top: 96px;    
  padding-right: 29px;
  padding-left: 48px;
}
```

When I see it in the browser, in the first page the "final" width of search_textbox is 187+48+29=264px. But when I insert the same thing in the second page and open it with the same browser the "final" width of search_textbox is only 187px.

I am testing it in Chrome and Mozilla. All of them show exactly the same picture.

Why? Am I doing something wrong or what?

**UPDATE 1**

I have noticed that in the second page Chrome is adding following style automatically, while in the first page it is not adding it:

```
input:not([type="image"]), textarea {                    user agent stylesheet
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I think this property is causing this error with the width, right? But I have searched in all my .css files and couldn't find that property at all. How Chrome is adding that property itself in one page and not adding in another page?

**UPDATE 2**

**I have solved the problem.** I have noticed that in the first page I had `<!DOCTYPE html>` statement but in the second one no, so once I have added that statement into the second page  the problem has been solved. But still I just wonder why?

Comment: Do both pages load the identical css? I'm just wondering if one of your pages loads extra CSS that has over-ridden one of your styles.

Comment: Can you show us an example of this? Otherwise we don't really have anything to go on to reproduce this result.

Comment: I have added updated section for additional info. Thnx

Comment: Do you have a URL we can go to where we can see this in action? There must be a different between the two pages otherwise Chrome would be treating both the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you've fixed your problem, this answer is a little superfluous, but whatever :-)

You probably know this already, but the `textarea`s width of `187px` is the default for your browser, which leads us nicely on to my next paragraph.

The reason CSS styles aren't fetched and parsed by a document with no doctype is due to the fact that, technically, it's not a valid document. Once you add the doctype, problem solved.

Comment: I see, thanks, now I am reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414891/whats-up-doctype to understand more.