# Best usages/practice of doctype in aspects of a user interface

Tags: html, user-interface

We have many kind of Web application on the web.
What kind of doctype we should prefer for Web UI Developments?

kindly post the url for reference.

Thanks

Comment: can you rephrase your question? It will help you get better answers

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's up, Doctype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414891/whats-up-doctype)

Comment: Yes..you are right its somewhat the same meaning but my concern is to choose a best doctype and their usages for a Web UI developments only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doctype declaration refers to a Document Type Definition (DTD). The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.

Refer following

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html

Comment: The rules specified in the DTD are ignored by pretty much all browsers in favour of their own internal rules. That W3Schools page has an above average number of errors for W3Schools (I'm having a hard time finding an error free paragraph on that page), and much as I usually like WDG … in this case it isn't much better.

Comment: The Web Design Group (WDG) was founded to promote the creation of non-browser specific, non-resolution specific, creative and informative sites that are accessible to all users worldwide. To this end, the WDG offers material on a wide range of HTML related topics. We hope that with this site as a reference, you will be able to create Web sites that can be used by every person on the Internet, regardless of browser, platform, or settings. http://htmlhelp.com/ refer this