# Regarding DOCTYPE in Tables

Tags: html, doctype

I need to know the importance of DOCTYPE..

Which will be good for tables?

when specifying doctype 4.01,table structure changes sometimes..

if we remove doctype,it is working perfect..

so i need help guidelines for usage of tables and doctype from stackoverflow users

Comment: Well - if you don't specify one, then the page will be rendered in `quirks` mode - Have a read about `doctypes` : http://alistapart.com/article/doctype

Comment: @Nick:thanks for spending time..let me know what is meant by quirks mode.

Comment: This is a matter of standards vs. quirks mode, well covered in answers to different versions of the same question. If you have a specific, concrete question (with code and description) not covered there, please ask it, not a vague and abstract question (with incorrect references—there is no “doctype 4.1”).

Answer (score 0):

What is Doctype:  ["<!DOCTYPE html>" What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346954/doctype-html-what-does-it-mean)

Doens't matter which one you will use, but you should use latest one - HTML5. Different behavior is mostly just CSS in different browsers which can be fixed by CSS Reset (http://bit.ly/QCpdbC).

Hope that I'll helps to you.