# how to know which <!DOCTYPE> type to use

Tags: html, types, document, doctype

i've searched and could not find any good explanation on here and on the internet many people outline what document types there are but don't explain how to determine which one would work best for your code....

so my question is how do i know which type of document type to declare in my webpage.....i know the difference between XHTML and HTML, i'm not asking that, i'm asking what type of document type such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

OR

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

an explanation or links would help.....i appreciate it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's up, Doctype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414891/whats-up-doctype)

Comment: There is a large number of old questions, with good (and bad) answers, about this at SO.

Comment: oh thanks for pointing that out.....i read through those threads and they were good discussions.....i just wanted to make sure as that thread is from 2009

Comment: We want to have answers to old questions updated, if needed, instead of spawning duplicates of questions with varying answers.

Comment: that makes sense.....i'll do that next time...thanks for the feedback...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use which you want, but in HTML 5 is recommend to use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What works best for you depends on what your situation is.

If you want your HTML page to work correctly on very very old browsers that don't support `<!DOCTYPE html>` (and yes, there were such browsers, like Netscape 6) then the strict doctype is really the only possibility.

If you want your HTML page to validate, AND you must, for some reason that you don't want to reveal, use elements like `<center>` or `<font>` or `<u>`, then transitional is the doctype of choice.

However, those are really edge cases, and you should consider forgetting about them. In the majority of cases, `<!DOCTYPE html>` will do. Don't look to the past; look to the future.

Comment: hey thanks a lot this makes sense...i am using <!DOCTYPE html> right now but was getting some funky behaviors in older versions of ie but i think that needs to be addressed with my css correct? i'll look into it....you know everyday i'm learning this stuff im' hating microsoft more and more for creating such crap (IE) and the extra work it takes.....stupid

Comment: Funky behaviours in older versions of IE? If you mean IE7 or below, not, that's not something you can fix with CSS. They just are funky.

Comment: Seriously, with a proper doctype declaration you are on the right track. Also make sure you have no errors in your HTML or your CSS; different browsers respond differently to errors. And to cater to older browsers, don't use CSS or HTML features that are too new.

Comment: If you're using Netscape6, then the fact that `<!DOCTYPE html>` causes quirks mode is the least of your problems.

Comment: @Alohci I'm fully aware of that; that's why I said the OP should forget about it. What I mean is that Netscp6 should receive as much attention as IE6, which is just about as old.

Comment: If only. IE6 was once the best browser around. It has regrettably stuck around, and it's still used by lots of people for various reasons. Did you ever use Netscape 6? It was utterly wretched from day 1. Anybody who went to the trouble of installing it, would have long ago got rid of it. But it doesn't matter. It was just a throwaway comment.

Comment: @Alohci I always keep various older versions of browsers around, to test how my websites look in them. So yes, at one time I did have Netscape 6 installed. And Internet Explorer 5. Naturally, these days, checking those would be silly; I now check with Firefox 3.5 and IE9 in IE7 mode.

Comment: This is a very confusing answer. To begin with, “the strict doctype is really the only possibility” really makes no sense. For all that we can know, the page might rely on Quirks Mode, or it might be mode-ignorant.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I was addressing the question of the OP, who had already decided that they wanted to use a doctype declaration, only they were not sure which one. And wanting to use a doctype is a good thing, because it prevents Quirks mode. Different browsers have different quirks! Honestly, I believe that building webpages to "rely on Quirks mode" in this day and age is a bit silly.

Comment: good discussion...i maintain an older website of the organization that i'm making this new website for and i have looked at the google analytics that the website has had for 3+ years....90% of windows users are using IE8 or better...we only get 50 hits per year with IE6 or IE7 and even with IE, it has been slowly decreasing since january of 2013....so i'm not going to waste a disproportionate amount of my time catering to 5% of people (which are not many in my case)....maybe i should just be thankful the website isn't super popular! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

But if you want to know when or why to use which one, see this page:

http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: hey yea i know the document types, but that link you sent doesn't explain how to know which one to use? maybe i'm missing something, i am new to html and css but i have just been writing in the way that has been taught through w3schools.com and codeacademy, so which doctype do they teach? that is my question...

Comment: @nojohnny101 - Currently w3schools teaches `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which is good. But what w3schools teaches is no recommendation at all. Previously, it taught the XHTML 1.0 doctype, which was a very poor choice for the time.

Comment: that is good to know.....i thought w3schools was the to go place, shakes my confidence a little bit that they used to teach XHTML 1.0.....maybe they (as a site) have improved...when was that?