# How to disable a submit button after submission in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I browsed through the other questions on this issue but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.
I have a quiz website where the user selects an option from four options and then clicks submit. I want to disable the submit button after it has been clicked once.

Is there any way to do this with PHP? If not, is there a way to do this with minimal JS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geniuscarrier/vTHm5/

Answer (score 3):

### Available Solutions

Since you tagged the question jQuery, here are some simple jQuery solutions you can use: 
To disable it when it is clicked, you can simply:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    this.disabled = true;
};
```

You can do even better though, and disable it only once the form is submitted:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

### Solution Demo

Here's a simple demo of the above logic, in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zb8CZ/ 
(Note that in that implementation I didn't use jQuery, but rather, plain JS; for portability across browsers however, as well as access to the many other methods jQuery provides (plus the syntactic sugar!) I recommend the jQuery methods.

### Good to note...

Note that attempting to implement JS event handling inline in your HTML (using the `onsubmit="..."` or `onclick="..."` attributes) is considered bad practice, since it muddles your functionality with your layout/display layer. You also lose any syntax highlighting and/or error-checking your editor might provide, as well as just generally making it harder to develop and maintain your application, since there is no logical order to your code.

Comment: the solutions seems to be working in the fiddle demo... I am, however a naive in jQuery or Javascript and do not know where to insert the Javascript in my code.... Please help..

Comment: Please can anyone answer this?

Comment: And should I place this in <head> ?

Comment: Given the nature of the question I think it's safe to assume that *"submission in PHP"* suggests a nice retro 1990's style form processing script whereby the back-end code does what it needs to in-line and also includes the same form in the output - which would make this solution pretty much useless as it stands.  The form still needs to submit and unless you specify otherwise the resultant output/page will have no knowledge of this...

Comment: Yes, the 'valuable' solution stand useless. Any suggestions from your side @Emissary ?

Answer (score 1):

I leave a code:

```
    <form name="myform" action="/" method="post" onsubmit="document.getElementById('submit_button').disabled = 1;">

<!-- form elements here -->

</form>
```

Comment: you are champion

Answer (score 0):

very easy javascript only method

```
<form action="" method="post" >
<input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" value="Submit Form"
   onclick="this.disabled='disabled';this.form.submit();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For disable write like this, after once click it will be disable.

```
<input type="submit" id="but_sub" name="submit" \>


    $("#but_sub").click(function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled",true);
    }
```

or

```
    $('#but_sub').click(function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You might want to pass the value of each answer to a PHP file that performs backend work via AJAX.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
    $('#question').submit(function(){
       //Get the value of the answer that was checked
       var answer = $('input:radio[name=question_one]:checked').val();

       //Use jQuery's AJAX function to send the data to a PHP file that does backend work 
       $.ajax({  
          type:'POST',  
          url:'quiz_backend.php',  
          data:'answer='+ answer,
          success: function() {
              //Hide the submit button upon successful submission
              $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
              event.preventDefault();
          }
       });
    });
</script>

<form id="question">
   <input type="radio" name="question_one" value="answer_one">A<br />
   <input type="radio" name="question_one" value="answer_two">B<br />
   <input type="radio" name="question_one" value="answer_three">C<br />
   <input type="radio" name="question_one" value="answer_four">D<br />

   <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

More info about jQuery's AJAX call [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Common practice these days would be to use AJAX but this doesn't answer the question, nor would any Javascript solution without any assistance from the back-end.  Say you have a form, for example:

```
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myVariable"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When submitting to your PHP file for processing you will be accessing your form data either via `$_GET` or `$_POST` and doing whatever you need to do with it.  At this point you will be able to deduce whether or not the form has been submitted or is successful - based on this you can simply flag either `input` or `button` elements with the `disabled` attribute, here's a basic example:

```
<?php # foo.php 
    $myVariable = isset($_POST['myVariable']) ? $_POST['myVariable'] : '';
    echo "You submitted: {$myVariable}\n"; // do something useful...

    // if variable is not an empty string, ie. it has been submitted,
    // set $disabled which can then be output in-line with your HTML
    $disabled   = ($myVariable != '') ? 'disabled' : '';
?>
<form action="foo.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="myVariable"/>
    <button type="submit" <?php echo $disabled; ?>>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This would then output your new form with the button disabled based on your conditions.  I should also note that depending on your `doctype` you may need to give the attribute a value for it to be considered valid markup, but generally speaking:

```
<!-- valid HTML5 -->
<button disabled>button</button>

<!-- valid XHTML -->
<button disabled="disabled">button</button>
```

---

*Some related StackOverflow reading:*

[What is a doctype?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/414993/1238344) 
[What does `?:` mean? (ternary operator)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1080256/1238344) 
[PHP: How can I submit a form via AJAX (jQuery version)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004276/1238344)

Comment: The submit button was bot disabled 'if(isset['myvariable']))' after ' $myVariable = isset($_POST['myVariable']) ? $_POST['myVariable'] : '';' 
If I do not use 'if isset($_POST['ans']))' the PHP code was left of no use.

Comment: @user2801699 I'm not sure what you are getting at - you'll have to post the relevant parts of your code so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I solved my concern by placing a div over the submit button after it is pressed once to prevent the user from pressiong it again. I know it is hackish, but I needed to get my site up Soon. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just try with below code. I hope it will help you...

```
    $('#contact-form').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $('.submit').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example registration button with User Message:**

```
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='ADD USER MESSAGE...';this.form.submit();" class="ADD BUTTON CLASS HERE" value="Register!">
```

```css
.sub-btn:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #406800;
  border-color: #82B33C;
  transition: all .25s linear;
  -o-transition: all .25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.sub-btn {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-family: 'Bitter', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #f8f8f8;
  background-color: #82B33C;
  border-color: #406800;
  transition: all .25s linear;
  -o-transition: all .25s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.tx-shadow {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.value='Creating Account, please wait...';this.form.submit();" class="sub-btn tx-shadow" value="Register!">
```