# Cakephp 3 How to prevent multiple form submissions

Tags: cakephp, form-submit

I've used the CsrfComponent, and I even implement the csrfToken by myself but neither of the solutions seem to work.

Here is my code:

view:

```
<?php $session->write('sCsrfToken', sha1(microtime())); ?>
<?= $this->Form->create(false)?>
<!-- Some input fields -->
<?= $this->Form->input('pCsrfToken', ['type' => 'hidden',
                         'value' =>  h($session->read('sCsrfToken'))]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->button('Submit') ?>
<?= $this->form->end();?>
```

controller:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
$sessionToken = $session->read('sCsrfToken');
$postToken    = $this->request->data('pCsrfToken');

if(empty($sessionToken) || $postToken != $sessionToken) {
throw new Exception();
} 
else {
$session->write('sCsrfToken', sha1(microtime())); 
//DB INSERT, SEND MAIL...
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: hi @Jay I'm trying to avoid multiple form submissions

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194356/how-to-disable-a-submit-button-after-submission-in-php